# Use Ajax to call php-code after page loaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got some php code that i want to execute when the page is fully loaded and i only want it to execute one time and no more after clicking submit.

this is the php code i want to execute

```
$backup=fopen("backup/".time().".json", "w");
    fwrite($backup, json_encode($list)); fclose($backup);
```

can someone tell me how to execute this code after page is loaded and only 1 time. If possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
//wait for the DOM to be loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $button = $('#idOfYourButton');
    $button.on('click', function(e){
    //if we have a submit button we probably do not want it to send the data via post/get
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
          url: "/your/path/file.php",
          success: function(){
              //do something when script was called 
          }
        });
    });
});
```

For the script to only run once, you have to define what this means. Once per session? Set a session flag on your server. Once per refresh? You can simply use a javascript variable.

Comment: Once you enter the page. The problem that i got now is that each time i press a button or something my page get reloaded again and it does the same thing again. What i want with this code is to make a backup each time someone enters the page and changes the original one so that if you make a mistake you can return the last saved file.

$filename = time() . '.json';
$backup=fopen("backup/".$filename, "w");
fwrite($backup, json_encode($list));
fclose($backup);

Comment: this is because you send the form. I edited my post to show how to stop this behaviour. However, it would make more sense to save all this information as session data. Have a look at window.localStorage and window.sessionStorage